# Lua's GC and realtime game

Tags: garbage-collection, lua, real-time

As I know, the tracing GC can't avoid thread blocking during complete GC.

I had used XNA+C#, and GC time were impossible to remove. So I switched to lower level language C, but I realized I need scripting language. I'm considering Lua, but I'm worrying about Lua's GC mechanism. Lua is using incremental tracing GC, and thread blocking should be too.

So how should I handle this in realtime game?

Comment: You either don't write a game with so tight FPS requirements in a GC'd language, or you don't create enough garbage to make a GC cycle take longer than acceptable. First try out whether there is any noticeable hit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The power of Lua is that it gets out of your way.  Want classes?  That can be build with metatables.  Want sandboxing? use [lua_setfenv](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_setfenv).

As for the garbage collector.  Use it as is first.  If later you find performance issues use [lua_gc](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_gc) to fine tune its behavior.

Some examples:

- Disable the garbage collector during those times when the slow down would be a problem.
- Leave the garbage collector disabled and only step it when game logic says you've got some head room on your FPS count.  You could pre-tune the step size, or discover the optimal step size at runtime.
- Disable the collector and perform full collection at stopping points, ie a load screen or cut scene or at turn change in a hot seat game.

You might also consider an alternative scripting language.  [Squirrel](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/) tries very hard to be a second generation Lua.  It tries to keep all of Lua's good features, while ditching any of its design mistakes.  One of the big differences between the two is [squirrel uses reference counting](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/viewreply.asp?ID=2257186) instead of garbage collection.  It turns out that reference counting can be a bit slower than garbage collection but it is very deterministic(AKA realtime).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your suggestion `Squirrel` looks very fine. I'll dig it soon :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to handle this is:

1. Write a small prototype with just the core things that you want to test.
2. Profile it a lot, reproducing the different scenarios that could happen in your game (lots of memory available, little memory available, different numbers of threads, that kind of thing)
3. If you don't find a visible bottleneck, you can use Lua. Otherwise, you will have to look for alternative solutions (maybe Lisp or Javascript)

Comment: It's sad this problem is non-avoidable, only can be reduced.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch the Lua GC so as to time-limit each collection cycle. E.g: http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/23/predictable-garbage-collection-with-lua/

I believe that it is still possible to have long GC step times when collecting very large tables. Therefore you need to adopt a programming style that avoids large tables.

The following article discusses two strategies for using Lua for real-time robot control (1. don't generate garbage, or 2. using an O(1) allocator and tune when GC collection is run):
https://www.osadl.org/?id=1117

Comment: The first link has gone 404. Fortunately it was a repost and the original can still be found here: http://kalogirou.net/2011/07/23/predictable-garbage-collection-with-lua/